# Find Target Thread of Invocation in Memory Dump Using Windbg

Tags: c#, multithreading, windbg, invoke, method-invocation

**Background**

A customer reported a hang in a C# application.  I have a memory dump at the point the application was hung.  The memory dump shows the main UI thread displaying a progress form and multiple background threads running.  One of the background threads is trying to Control.Invoke back to the main thread to update the form.  The CLR stack looks like this:

```
System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean) 
System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int64, Boolean) 
System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32, Boolean) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WaitForWaitHandle(System.Threading.WaitHandle) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Delegate, System.Object[], Boolean) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[]) 
profdata.com.Library.frmAsyncExec.SetMessageText(System.String) 
profdata.com.Library.frmAsyncExec.SetMessage(System.String, System.String) 
profdata.com.Library.frmAsyncExec.DoAsyncProcess(System.Object) 
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object) 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object) 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object) 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) 
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)
```

The UI thread is in a modal loop and awaiting a message:

```
System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.WaitMessage() 
System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32, Int32, Int32) 
System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext) 
System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext) 
System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(System.Windows.Forms.Form) 
System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window) 
profdata.com.Library.frmAppletBaseForm.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window) 
profdata.com.Library.frmAsyncExec.ExecuteProcess(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window)
```

I verified that the only message in the message queue (that I can see) is a paint message.  Message 15 corresponds to WM_PAINT:

```
0:000> !dso
OS Thread Id: 0x126c (0)
ESP/REG  Object   Name
ebx      01a688d0 System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext
esi      01a6eb9c System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager+ComponentHashtableEntry
edi      1b0c05e0 System.Collections.Hashtable+HashtableEnumerator
0036e244 1b08430c System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods+MSG[]

0:000> !da 1b08430c 
Name: System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods+MSG[]
MethodTable: 67e0592c
EEClass: 67be89b8
Size: 40(0x28) bytes
Array: Rank 1, Number of elements 1, Type VALUETYPE
Element Methodtable: 67e059dc

0:000> !dumpvc 67e059dc 1b084314
Name: System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods+MSG
MethodTable 67e059dc
EEClass: 67bbd880
Size: 36(0x24) bytes
 (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll)
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
691b35f0  4002ba0        0        System.IntPtr  1 instance    b02ee hwnd
691b2f74  4002ba1        4         System.Int32  1 instance       15 message
691b35f0  4002ba2        8        System.IntPtr  1 instance        0 wParam
691b35f0  4002ba3        c        System.IntPtr  1 instance        0 lParam
691b2f74  4002ba4       10         System.Int32  1 instance 264314085 time
691b2f74  4002ba5       14         System.Int32  1 instance      188 pt_x
691b2f74  4002ba6       18         System.Int32  1 instance      386 pt_y
```

I know that Control.MarshaledInvoke is implemented as a PostMessage of a known message:

```
private object MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, object[] args, bool synchronous)
{
    ...
    System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.PostMessage(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), threadCallbackMessage, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    ...
}
```

MSDN says this about [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Places (posts) a message in the message queue associated with the
>   thread that created the specified window and returns without waiting
>   for the thread to process the message.

I suspect that this is a classic case of a background thread accessing a UI object which is known to cause application hangs.  I am well aware this is a bad thing.

Since there are multiple background threads, I would like to determine which background thread messed up.

**Question**

Is it possible to determine the destination thread for the call to Control.Invoke using information in the memory dump?

**Work So Far**

I've gotten a dump of the stack objects of the background thread:

```
0:000> ~20s
0:020> !dso
OS Thread Id: 0x5d8 (20)
ESP/REG  Object   Name
ecx      01a2b2d0 System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context
0c42e49c 1b083e20 System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
0c42e524 01a2006c System.Collections.Hashtable
0c42e560 1b083e38 Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle
0c42e5fc 1b044128 System.Windows.Forms.PropertyStore
0c42e608 1b060b68 System.Collections.Queue
0c42e610 1b083de0 System.Windows.Forms.Control+ThreadMethodEntry
0c42e65c 1b043b30 profdata.com.DailyReporting.frmDRAsyncExec
0c42e66c 1b083cb0 System.Object[]    (System.Object[])
0c42e670 1b083c90 profdata.com.Library.frmAsyncExec+SetMessageDelegate
0c42e674 1b083cc4 System.Windows.Forms.Control+MultithreadSafeCallScope
0c42e694 1b043b30 profdata.com.DailyReporting.frmDRAsyncExec
```

I've tried looing at the ThreadMethodEntry and the Context object, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for:

```
0:020> !do 1b083de0 
Name: System.Windows.Forms.Control+ThreadMethodEntry
MethodTable: 67e05380
EEClass: 67be8454
Size: 52(0x34) bytes
 (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll)
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
67dff750  40011b9        4 ...ows.Forms.Control  0 instance 1b043b30 caller
67dff750  40011ba        8 ...ows.Forms.Control  0 instance 1b043b30 marshaler
691b118c  40011bb        c      System.Delegate  0 instance 1b083c90 method
691844f8  40011bc       10      System.Object[]  0 instance 1b083cb0 args
691b0944  40011bd       14        System.Object  0 instance 00000000 retVal
691b0ebc  40011be       18     System.Exception  0 instance 00000000 exception
691847f4  40011bf       2c       System.Boolean  1 instance        1 synchronous
691847f4  40011c0       2d       System.Boolean  1 instance        0 isCompleted
69197b54  40011c1       1c ....ManualResetEvent  0 instance 1b083e20 resetEvent
691b0944  40011c2       20        System.Object  0 instance 1b083e14 invokeSyncObject
691ada1c  40011c3       24 ....ExecutionContext  0 instance 1b083cd0 executionContext
691aa00c  40011c4       28 ...ronizationContext  0 instance 00000000 syncContext

0:020> !do 01a2b2d0 
Name: System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context
MethodTable: 691a210c
EEClass: 68fcf620
Size: 60(0x3c) bytes
 (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
691844f8  4001f60        4      System.Object[]  0 instance 01a2b3a0 _ctxProps
691a219c  4001f61        8 ...micPropertyHolder  0 instance 00000000 _dphCtx
691a75b4  4001f62        c ...em.LocalDataStore  0 instance 00000000 _localDataStore
69196f18  4001f63       10 ...ging.IMessageSink  0 instance 00000000 _serverContextChain
69196f18  4001f64       14 ...ging.IMessageSink  0 instance 00000000 _clientContextChain
691b1508  4001f65       18     System.AppDomain  0 instance 01a01298 _appDomain
691844f8  4001f66       1c      System.Object[]  0 instance 00000000 _ctxStatics
691b35f0  4001f67       20        System.IntPtr  1 instance   551520 _internalContext
691b2f74  4001f68       24         System.Int32  1 instance        0 _ctxID
691b2f74  4001f69       28         System.Int32  1 instance        3 _ctxFlags
691b2f74  4001f6a       2c         System.Int32  1 instance        1 _numCtxProps
691b2f74  4001f6b       30         System.Int32  1 instance        0 _ctxStaticsCurrentBucket
691b2f74  4001f6c       34         System.Int32  1 instance        0 _ctxStaticsFreeIndex
691a219c  4001f6d      654 ...micPropertyHolder  0   shared   static _dphGlobal
    >> Domain:Value  00557ff8:01a2b068 <<
69189944  4001f6e      658 ...LocalDataStoreMgr  0   shared   static _localDataStoreMgr
    >> Domain:Value  00557ff8:01a2b07c <<
691b2f74  4001f6f      b40         System.Int32  1   shared   static _ctxIDCounter
    >> Domain:Value  00557ff8:0 <<
```

Or maybe there is a more native approach that involves finding the association of the window handle to a specific thread, but if so, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Woudn't accessing UI objects from other threads throw InvalidOperationException? I think it would, and that will just kill the thread, unless you are catching it and handling somehow (which is a bad idea in general). With killed thread you only have a chance to search for objects of type InvalidOperationException in the GC heap, unless it is already collected.

Comment: `Control.MarshaledInvoke` would throw an InvalidOperationException if the Handle was not created.  The `Handle` property would only throws InvalidOperationException if a debugger is attached:  `private static bool checkForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = Debugger.IsAttached;`

Comment: hey, did u solve this problem? could please share?

Comment: @thewpfguy I don't think I did, but it's been so long that I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dump in your ThreadMethodEntry the delegate (method field) that is executed on the UI thread. The other members are only there so that the UI thread knows to which control to send the callback and in which Synchronization context it is executed.

There are also some flags to check if an invoke is necessary at all and an exception field if the call did fail which can be marshalled back to the caller if it was done via a Invoke call. You can safely ignore the other stuff there.

More infos how you can find out which method was called when you only have a delegate instance at your hands you find here: http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2012/05/20/149699.aspx

Since your callback is not even executed you should have a look at the other threads as well. Such mysterious hangs do often happen in conjunction with a WM_SETTING_CHANGE window message where a non UI thread tries to call into your controls (see http://ikriv.com/dev/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html#BeginInvokeDance).